# Make dictionary with specific format from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Trying to convert the dataframe

[image]

Into a dictionary with this specific structure:

```
    sales = { 
   "clients": [
       {"ID_client": "241341", 
       "purchases": [
            "Item 101",
            "Item 202",
            "Item 324",
        ],
        "payment": [
            "visa", "master", "visa"
        ]           
       },
       {"ID_client": "24356", 
       "purchases": [
            "Item 2320",
            "Item 2342",
            "Item 5604",
        ],
        "payment": [
            "diners", "cash", "diners"
        ]           
       },    
       {"ID_client": "5534", 
       "purchases": [
            "Item 50563",
            "Item 52878",
            "Item 54233",
        ],
        "payment": [
            "diners", "master", "visa"
        ]           
       }       
   ]

}
```

I've been trying with some for loops like:

```
 d = {"sales":[]}
  for i in df1['ID_Client'].unique():/
     clients = {"ID_client": df1['ID_client'][i]}
     d[i] = [{df1['purchases'][j]: df1['payment'][j]} for j in 
     df1[df1['ID_Client']==i].index]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you explored [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't get the answer I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your source *DataFrame* is *df*, your dictionary can be generated
with a **single** instruction:

```
sales = { 'clients' : df.groupby(df.ID_client)\
    .agg(list)\
    .reset_index()\
    .set_axis(['ID_client', 'purchases', 'payment'], axis=1, inplace=False)\
    .to_dict('records')
}
```

As you can see, creation of the array - content of *clients* consists
actually of the following chain:

- **groupby** - group *df* by *ID_client*,
- **agg** - aggregate all the remaining columns (*Purchase* and *Payment*),
  into lists of values, for now *ID_client* is the index,
- **reset_index** to make *ID_client* an ordinary data column,
- **set_axis** - change column names (the names of target components are
  slightly different from source column names),
- **to_dict** - create the result dictionary.

The content of **sales** variable is:

```
{'clients': [{'ID_client': '241341',
   'purchases': ['Item 101', 'Item 202', 'Item 324'],
   'payment': ['visa', 'master', 'visa']},
  {'ID_client': '24356',
   'purchases': ['Item 2320', 'Item 2342', 'Item 5604'],
   'payment': ['diners', 'cash', 'diners']},
  {'ID_client': '5534',
   'purchases': ['Item 50563', 'Item 52878', 'Item 54233'],
   'payment': ['diners', 'master', 'visa']}]}
```

just as you wish.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! @Valdi_Bo

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `np.repeat` and `itertools.chain`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(sales['clients'])

res = pd.DataFrame({'ID_client': np.repeat(df['ID_client'], df['payment'].map(len)),
                    'payment': list(chain.from_iterable(df['payment'])),
                    'purchases': list(chain.from_iterable(df['purchases']))})

print(res)

  ID_client payment   purchases
0    241341    visa    Item 101
0    241341  master    Item 202
0    241341    visa    Item 324
1     24356  diners   Item 2320
1     24356    cash   Item 2342
1     24356  diners   Item 5604
2      5534  diners  Item 50563
2      5534  master  Item 52878
2      5534    visa  Item 54233
```

Note with this method each unique index aligns with an `ID_client`, as per your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track with the start of your loop, but you'll be better off using the results to filter the dataframe.  Should be more efficient and more panda like (pandaren?) to do it that way.

Example:

```
clients = []
for c in df1['ID_client'].unique():
    client = {
        'ID_client': c, 
        'purchases': list(df1[df1.ID_client == c].loc[:, 'Purchase']), 
        'payment': list(df1[df1.ID_client == c].loc[:, 'Payment'])
    }
    clients.append(client)
```